# When open add new post or page Wordpress add post with ID=0 continuously

Tags: posts, pages, database

When open add new post or page Wordpress add post with ID=0 continuously. and instead of `publish` there is `submit for review`

[image]

Comment: Sounds like there is a plugin involved. Have you disabled all plugins and switched to a bundled theme?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your user has permission to publish.

Some WordPress setups users such as authors do not have permission to publish posts directly, instead they can submit them for review for an admin to review and decide whether the post should be published or not.

It is not a great idea to use an administrator user on daily basis so sometimes people create an author user for themselves without realizing that role does not have permission to publish without an administrator user reviewing the post.

If I'm right you need to grant your user role permission to publish or change your user role to one that has that sort of permissions.

Comment: Please add an explanation why this would solve the problem.

Comment: Sure. I some WordPress setups users such as authors do not have permission to publish posts directly, instead they can submit them for review for an admin to review and decide whether the post should be published or not.

It is not a great idea to use an administrator user on daily basis so sometimes people create an author user for themselves without realizing that role does not have permission to publish without an administrator user reviewing the post.